# Alert managment

Tags: alert, custom-list

I'm using SharePoint 2007,

I create custom list.
on that list I create alert designed for 3 people.

now I want to change the alert definition for these people,
but when I enter to the alert list I can only see the alerts are for me.

how can I manege all the alert that I defined on my list?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a management tool available to look at alerts per list. You can go to Site Settings, and Manage Alerts there per user.

Comment: from site testting page, can I edit the alert? or jast delete the alert?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, I haven't used 2007 in a while. Can you go there and take a look?

Comment: @liron From SharePoint 2013 Foundation, you cannot alter the alerts but you can delete them. And then you could recreate them as desired.